# Select previous and following values in list in R

Tags: r, row, extra

I have a list object, where the first column is mass and the second is abundance. Here a short example:

```
772.35 0 
772.9 10 
773.81 0
...
885.64 0 
885.65 10 
885.68 313 
885.70 4455 
885.78 71 
885.82 0
...
889.12 0
889.13 56 
885.82 0
...
900.31 0 
900.34 10 
901.22 1901 
902.8 0
```

I have to select rows where the abundance > 100  as a serie starting with 0 and ending with 0. The result will be:

```
885.64 0 
885.65 10 
885.68 313 
885.70 4455 
885.78 71 
885.82 0
900.31 0 
900.34 10 
901.22 1901 
902.8 0
```

The serie may contains two abundances > 100 `(885.68 313 and 885.70 4455)` but my result must be without duplicate

Data

```
dd <- read.table(text = "772.35 0 
                 772.9 10 
                 773.81 0
                 885.64 0 
                 885.65 10 
                 885.68 313 
                 885.70 4455 
                 885.78 71 
                 885.82 0
                 889.12 0
                 889.13 56 
                 885.82 0
                 900.31 0 
                 900.34 10 
                 901.22 1901 
                 902.8 0")
```

Comment: Why have you left `772.35 0 
772.9 10 
773.81 0` set? Those starts with `0` and ends with `0` as well.

Comment: This given sample data is insufficient to ensure that the solution is robust. Please provide a sample of rows which we can use to build a nice solution.

Comment: Because abundance (10) is < 100. It will be eliminated in the result

Comment: `dd[!!ave(dd$V2, c(0, cumsum(diff(dd$V2) == 0)), FUN = function(x) any(x > 100)), ]`

Comment: Is it s data.frame or list? Please `dput` output on your object.

Answer (score 1):

```
setDT(dd)[,group:=cumsum(c(diff(as.numeric(!V2)),0)<0)][,b:=any(V2>100),by=group][!!b]
        V1   V2 group    b
 1: 885.64    0     2 TRUE
 2: 885.65   10     2 TRUE
 3: 885.68  313     2 TRUE
 4: 885.70 4455     2 TRUE
 5: 885.78   71     2 TRUE
 6: 885.82    0     2 TRUE
 7: 900.31    0     4 TRUE
 8: 900.34   10     4 TRUE
 9: 901.22 1901     4 TRUE
10: 902.80    0     4 TRUE
```