# Select sub-dataframe between two values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame object, where the first column is mass and the second is abundance.

```
dd <- read.table(text = "771.55 0
                  772.35 0 
                 772.9 10 
                 773.81 0
                 885.64 0 
                 885.65 110 
                 885.68 313 
                 885.70 313 
                 885.78 71 
                 885.82 0
                 889.12 0
                 889.13 506 
                 885.82 0
                 900.31 0 
                 900.34 10 
                 901.22 1901 
                 902.8 0
                 908.8 0")
```

I have to select only sub-dataframe with consecutive zero value (starting with 0 and ending with 0) in the second column with abundance (second column value) > 100. The result must be:

```
list1 <- read.table(text= "885.64 0
                          885.65 110 
                          885.68 313 
                          885.70 313 
                          885.78 71 
                          885.82 0")

list3 <- read.table(text= "889.12 0
                          889.13 506 
                          885.82 0")
```

...etc

Someone suggested this solution:

```
dd[!!ave(dd$V2, c(0, cumsum(diff(dd$V2) == 0)), FUN = function(x) any(x > 100)), ]
```

It works very well, but it cuted also when their is duplicate abundance value. Instead of cutting:

```
list <- read.table(text= "885.64 0 
             885.65 110 
             885.68 313 
             885.70 313 
             885.78 71 
             885.82 0")
```

It cuts wrongly in the middle of the serie:

```
list <- read.table(text= "885.64 0 
                 885.65 110 
                 885.68 313")

list <- read.table(text= "885.70 313 
                 885.78 71 
                 885.82 0")
```

Comment: *" select only series starting with 0 and ending with 0 with abundance > 100"*; which column entries denote abundance? Which column entries are you checking for start/end values? Can you please edit your post to include your expected output based on your sample data?

Comment: How do you handle the first two zeros? i.e. what happens if you have two consecutive abundance as 0?

Comment: If you were to check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038027/select-previous-and-following-values-in-list-in-r/49039189#49039189) you will notice that i did gave an answer to this question. Just save the result as dat2 and do split(dat2,dat2$group)

Comment: The first zero belongs to the previous sub-dataframe and I have to cut at each two consecutive zero values

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `data.table` to construct a grouping variable:

```
library("data.table")
dt <- fread(
  "x y
771.55 0
772.35 0 
772.9 10 
773.81 0
885.64 0 
885.65 10 
885.68 313 
885.70 313 
885.78 71 
885.82 0
889.12 0
889.13 506 
885.82 0
900.31 0 
900.34 10 
901.22 1901 
902.8 0
908.8 0")
dt[, ':='(y2=shift(y), y3=shift(y, type="lead"))]
dt[, ':='(start=(y==0 & y3>0), stop=(y==0 & y2>0))]
dt[, group:=(rleid(start, stop)+1)%/%3]
dt[, if (.N>=3 && max(y)>100) .SD[, .(x, y)], group]
# > dt[, if (.N>=3 && max(y)>100) .SD[, .(x, y)], group]
#    group      x    y
# 1:     2 885.64    0
# 2:     2 885.65   10
# 3:     2 885.68  313
# 4:     2 885.70  313
# 5:     2 885.78   71
# 6:     2 885.82    0
# 7:     3 889.12    0
# 8:     3 889.13  506
# 9:     3 885.82    0
# 10:    4 900.31    0
# 11:    4 900.34   10
# 12:    4 901.22 1901
# 13:    4 902.80    0
```

Here is a short variant:

```
dt[, group:=rleidv(y==0 & shift(y)==0) %/%2][, if (.N>2 && max(y)>100) .SD, group]
```

Comment: The for any group second column must have vakues greater than 100. Your first group do es not meet that condition

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks for the comment. So I have to do a further selection. I will edit my answer. ... done

Answer (score 1):

```
 library(data.table) 
 A=setDT(dd)[,group:=cumsum(c(diff(as.numeric(!V2)),0)<0)][,
              b:=any(V2>100),by=group][!!b][,b:=NULL]

 split(A,A$group)
$`2`
       V1  V2 group
1: 885.64   0     2
2: 885.65 110     2
3: 885.68 313     2
4: 885.70 313     2
5: 885.78  71     2
6: 885.82   0     2

$`3`
       V1  V2 group
1: 889.12   0     3
2: 889.13 506     3
3: 885.82   0     3

$`4`
       V1   V2 group
1: 900.31    0     4
2: 900.34   10     4
3: 901.22 1901     4
4: 902.80    0     4
5: 908.80    0     4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `data.table` solution which uses a *non-equi join* and groups within the join:

```
library(data.table)
# coerce to data.table and append row numbers
setDT(dd)[, rn := .I]
# find start and end indices of subsequences from zero to zero
mdt <- dd[, {tmp = .I[V2 == 0]; .(beg = head(tmp, -1L), end = tail(tmp, -1L))}]
# non-equi join of index ranges and group within the join 
# to return only subsequences which fulfill the condition
result <- dd[mdt, on = .(rn >= beg, rn <= end), .SD[any(V2 > 100)], by = .EACHI][
  # return mass, abundance, and group id
  , .(V1, V2, rleid(rn))]

result
```

> ```
>         V1   V2 V3
>  1: 885.64    0  1
>  2: 885.65  110  1
>  3: 885.68  313  1
>  4: 885.70  313  1
>  5: 885.78   71  1
>  6: 885.82    0  1
>  7: 889.12    0  2
>  8: 889.13  506  2
>  9: 885.82    0  2
> 10: 900.31    0  3
> 11: 900.34   10  3
> 12: 901.22 1901  3
> 13: 902.80    0  3
> ```

The grouping variable `V3` should be sufficient for further group-wise processing. However, if it is required to separate the sub-data tables:

```
split(result, by = "V3")
```

> ```
> $`1`
>        V1  V2 V3
> 1: 885.64   0  1
> 2: 885.65 110  1
> 3: 885.68 313  1
> 4: 885.70 313  1
> 5: 885.78  71  1
> 6: 885.82   0  1
>
> $`2`
>        V1  V2 V3
> 1: 889.12   0  2
> 2: 889.13 506  2
> 3: 885.82   0  2
>
> $`3`
>        V1   V2 V3
> 1: 900.31    0  3
> 2: 900.34   10  3
> 3: 901.22 1901  3
> 4: 902.80    0  3
> ```